# How do I show that the binary representation on the real line is uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do I show that the binary representation on the real line is uncountable? Thanks.

Comment: You mean $2^{\bf N}$? Ever heard of Cantor and his famous diagonalization argument? It shows that every countable subset of $2^{\bf N}$ is proper.

Comment: I have to select an umber randomly from[0,1),and then show that the binaty representation is uncountable.

Comment: "The binary representation is uncountable"? What does that mean?

Comment: That is what I am thinking,like for example,(0.1)2 in binary means 0.5 and (0.11)2 in binary means 0.5+0.25=0.75.So how do i prove that this numbers are uncountable.

Comment: **Sets** can be catalogued as *countable* or *uncountable*, **not** numbers. Your question makes no sense as it stands. Don't you mean $2^{\bf N}$, which can be thought of as the set of all infinite strings of $0$s and $1$s?

Comment: Okay we can go with that.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking to show that the set of all infinitely long binary strings is uncountable. This can be seen intuitively by considering a string $x=x_1x_2\ldots$ where $x_i \in \{0,1\}$. The letters in this string have an obvious bijection to $\mathbb{N}$, taking $1 \to x_1$, $2 \to x_2$ and so on (so there are countably many characters in this string). Then, we have $2$ options for each position in the string, meaning there are $2^\mathbb{N}$ possible infinite binary strings which is uncountable by Cantor diagonalization.